# Empty permissions array not getting the right auth callback under iOS

Tags: ios, authentication, permissions, facebook-oauth

Our iOS app required the 'publish_stream' permission. We're now removing it and passing in an empty string NSArray but it doesn't reflect in the auth screen.

It keeps telling the user "This app may post on your behalf, including status updates, photos and more." and we can't seem to reset that.

```
- (void)facebookLogin
{
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"",nil]; // was @"publish_stream"
    // Look here for a list of available permissions:
    // http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/
    [_facebook authorize:permissions];
}
```

We tried passing in nil instead of the empty string NSArray but that didn't help.
Are there auth options to be adjusted in the App Settings of the developers page?

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Gon

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a recent bug. See the developer forums [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/273948536030203?browse=search_4f9024e9e3a232279544264). Hopefully they'll be resolving it soon.